# how to set default state in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning my way to React.

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
        company: '',
        website: '',
        location: '',
        position: 'Student',
    });
```

This is my form state, which initially sets position to 'Student' and so on. 
But when I opened up react dev tool, the 'state' is just an empty object. How do I set the default object state according to what's given in useState({...})? useEffect can achieve that goal but I don't want to write extra codes for assigning each individual field..

[image]

Comment: It works, right? The issue is just how it looks like in the dev tool. You have an error there (the red triangle), put your mouse over it and see what it says.

Comment: If you still can log the form's value and update, then I think it's fine then. Perhaps it doesn't render the right way in your dev tool.

Answer (score -1):

It's recommended to lazy initialize your state when we create a complex object or any complex calculation to initialize the state. State initialization is a one-time process so don't need to pass an object directly, React will create a new object on each rerender. You should pass a function that will return your state and react will call this function only once. For better understanding please follow this [blog Written by Kent C. Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-state-lazy-initialization-and-function-updates)

```
const [form, setForm] = useState(() => ({
    company: '',
    website: '',
    location: '',
    position: 'Student',
}));
```

Comment: From the linked post: “This is called ’lazy initialization.’ It's a performance optimization. You shouldn't have to use it a whole lot, but it can be useful in some situations, […]. I would say I use this only 2% of the time. It's not really a feature I use often.”

Comment: Yes, lazy initialization is a performance optimization not needed for every setState call

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem?